# How to compute the standard deviation with a "number" column?

Tags: mysql

I have this table in MySQL :

```
value    number_ads
1        3
2        1
3        1
3        1
4        1
```

I would like to compute the standard deviation of the column value, but taking into account that the value 1 for example should be counted 3 times.

The result should be :

```
AVG = 2.1429     STD = 1.124858267715973
```

I tried with this following request, but I don't have the good result:

```
SELECT 
SUM(value * number_ads) / SUM(number_ads) AS avg,
SQRT((SUM(POW(value, 2)) - POW(2.1429, 2))/SUM(number_ads)) 
FROM `test`
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the square root of variance. Variance is the difference between mean of (squares of values) and square of mean i.e, Sum(x*x)/Count(n) - Mean*Mean.

```
SELECT 
SUM(value * number_ads) / SUM(number_ads) AS avg,
SQRT((SUM(POW(value ,2) * number_ads)/SUM(number_ads)) - avg * avg)
FROM `test`
```

[Source](https://www.strchr.com/standard_deviation_in_one_pass)